# A query to show max_length_name_city and min_length_name_city ordering by alfabet when having more than one city

Tags: mysql, sql

Why is my query wrong?

```
SELECT MIN(city), LENGTH(MIN(city))
FROM station 
ORDER BY MIN(city) ASC 
LIMIT 1;

SELECT MAX(city), LENGTH(MAX(city)) 
FROM station 
ORDER BY MAX(city) ASC  
LIMIT 1;
```

The statement of the question:
Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

Sample Input

For example, CITY has four entries:

```
CITY 
----
DEF 
ABC 
PQRS
WXY
```

Sample Output

```
ABC 3
PQRS 4
```

Explanation
When ordered alphabetically, the CITY names are listed as ABC, DEF, PQRS, and WXY, with lengths  and . The longest name is PQRS, but there are  options for shortest named city. Choose ABC, because it comes first alphabetically.

Note
You can write two separate queries to get the desired output. It need not be a single query.

Comment: what mysql version?

Comment: @forpas rolled back your edit because you changed the sample output from maybe having 1 row to having 2 rows

Comment: None in particular. It's a Hackerrank exercise.

Comment: @forpas never mind, apparently you were correct: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5/problem

Answer (score 1):

`MIN(city)` is the lexically minimum city.  So given "Aachen" and "Dover", it will be "Aachen".  And `LENGTH(MIN(city))` is the length of that city, so 6, not 5.

To get the shortest city name, you want something like:

```
select min(city), length(city)
from station
group by length(city)
order by length(city)
limit 1;
```

By grouping by length, `min(city)` will find the lexically least city name for each length.

Similarly, for the longest name:

```
select min(city), length(city)
from station
group by length(city)
order by length(city) desc
limit 1;
```

(still selecting the lexically first city name for each length, but ordering by descending length instead of ascending length).

To get both in a single query is easiest to do with window functions (requires mysql 8.0 or mariadb 10.2 or above):

```
select
    first_value(city) over minlen,
    first_value(length(city)) over minlen,
    first_value(city) over maxlen,
    first_value(length(city)) over maxlen
from station
window
    minlen as (order by length(city),city),
    maxlen as (order by length(city) desc,city)
limit 1;
```

In earlier versions, it's easiest to do this like so:

```
select
    substr(min(concat(lpad(length(city),8,0),city)),9),
    min(length(city)),
    substr(min(concat(99999999-length(city),city)),9),
    max(length(city))
from station;
```

(which may appear to be a simpler query, but won't be able to use an index on city).

Comment: Thanks ysth. The complete answer worked (with MAX(city) and ODER BY with DESC) worked.

Comment: Which complete answer?  No answer should include `max(city)`, that would be wrong

Comment: The submitted code that worked was:
`SELECT MIN(city), LENGTH(city)`
`FROM station`
`GROUP BY LENGTH(city)`
`ORDER BY LENGTH(city)`
`LIMIT 1;`
`SELECT MAX(city), LENGTH(city)`
`FROM station`
`GROUP BY LENGTH(city)`
`ORDER BY LENGTH(city) DESC`
`LIMIT 1;`

Comment: because they ask for the min and the max length name.

Comment: @KPC that is wrong; that will return the longest city name that comes last alphabetically, not the one that comes first.  you want MIN for both the longest and shortest queries

Comment: It seems to me that you are right. The question is poorly worded. I will comment on it there.

Comment: I found a solution that seems ok. Simple but correct. `SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS city_name_len`
`FROM station`
`GROUP BY city`
`ORDER BY city_name_len ASC, city ASC`
`LIMIT 1;`

`SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS city_name_len`
`FROM station`
`GROUP BY city`
`ORDER BY city_name_len DESC, city ASC`
`LIMIT 1;`

Comment: that seems right, though I don't think it needs the GROUP BYs.  but what you had in your previous comment was right too if you just change MAX to MIN